# Extracting numeric part from string - SYBASE ASE

Tags: sap-ase

I am trying to extract the 7658 from string `XYZ.ABC7658@YAHOO.CO.IN`. 
Below is the query which I am trying and the output is also shown. However the query doesn't server the purpose.

Can you please help on this?
(Running Query on Sybase ASE)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('XYZ.ABC7658@YAHOO.CO.IN', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'XYZ.ABC7658@YAHOO.CO.IN'),   
       LEN('XYZ.ABC7658@YAHOO.CO.IN')) as number

Go

 Number
 --------------
 85@YAHOO.CO.IN
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention the end poistion

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @str='XYZ.ABC7658@YAHOO.CO.IN'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]%', @str) + 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @str) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]%', @str))
```